# Spring Cloud Config- Customizing the Bootstrap context to read config URI from another property Source

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

So I have the following use case-

I need to customize the bootstrap context to read the uri where the config Server lies from a particular file and then inject that uri into the property spring.cloud.config.uri to get properties from the configServer.

I have been looking at documentation on Spring cloud commons and have experimented around customizing Bootstrap property sources. This, unfortunately does not work, because this acts as another source of properties for the application context, not a source of properties for the bootstrap context( bootstrap.yml or properties).

The only solution I have so far, which is probably not the most elegant one is to set the uri property as a system property before we run the spring Application.

So, something like the following.

```
            public static void main(String args[]) {

            * Read properties from file and set as system properties*
            System.setProperty("uri","http://localhost:8097");
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

          }
```

And then reference the above property in bootstrap.properties as-

```
          spring.cloud.config.uri=${uri}
```

This works and is okay,but i would like to do this still in a more Spring Friendly way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not define the property using -Duri=someuri while starting the application instead of hardcoding like this?

Comment: cant do that, i have actually configured basic username/password security on my configServer and am embedding username/password curl style in the url itself. This needs to go into production , so nothing can be in plaintext. The file i am reading from is only available decrypted at runtime, so yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this cant be done.

You can change the location of bootstrap.yml/properties using config

```
                 spring.cloud.bootstrap.location
```

But , you cannot add a bean to read properties which will be part of the Bootstrap context, as the Bootstrap Context will be the parent of the most senior ancestor created by the user himself.

Comment: What do you mean with "You can change the location of bootstrap.yml/properties using config"?
What is "config" there?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use run arg arguments and give a defult value like this:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=${config.uri:http://localhost:8097}

java jar xxx.jar --config.uri=http://localhost:8099
```

Comment: The answer question box is only for complete answers to the question. This feels more like a comment. If you are not sure if it works, please test the solution and edit the question to make it sound like an official answer rather than a guess. Or, if you were wrong, just delete it as it will not be useful to others.

Comment: @NightOwl888 sorry,I can't add a comment,because it show me must have 50 reputation.so what can i do?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can either test your solution and then edit the answer (remove "I think") or if you find the solution doesn't work, you can delete the answer. Getting 50 reputation can be done fastest by answering questions, but make sure that they are working answers so you can gain upvotes instead of downvotes.

Comment: Not to be rude as such, but the above answer won’t work. I would recommend you to post questions and only add answers if ur absolutely sure and test if something works. Anyways, welcome to the community! :)